# Dataformat description best practice

Tags: standards, dataformat

I need a flexible way to describe a data format. Length, data type, description etc.

I thought of using xml to deine each object because it would be easy to parse for different languages.

Is this the best practice when doing this or is there any defined standards?

Comment: This is a very general question. Can you add some information about the intended usage?

Comment: A example would be that data is sent as a csv string with the first column as a dataobject identifier. The sender and the receiver could validate the data format on each side by using the xml description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XML in the end to solve my problem and so far it works great.